# AlarmManager Multiple Alarms

Tags: android, android-intent

Just a quick question.

I know how to set multiple alarms by assigning a unique id to each one, but if a user wants to set an alarm for 9am, 12pm, 3pm and 7pm on Monday, Wednesday and Friday, does that mean I have to set up 12 alarms?

Following on from that, if they wanted to set the alarm for the same times for 6 days of the week, is that 24 alarms, whereas if it was for the full week it would be just 4 alarms?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: "I've included commonsware in the tags because I've subscribed to the warescription and there is no information about this in any of the books" -- please re-read the preface to learn about the role of this tag with respect to the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AlarmManager` has only basic API. So you may use `setRepeating` for 9am, 12pm, 3pm, 7pm and then ignore the alarm on specific days.

Comment: So I would set each alarm as INTERVAL_DAY (4 alarms) and when it's called, check the database as to whether it should be displayed?

Comment: Yes you're right. Although I'm not sure AlarmManager stores alarms after power off.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'd be doing the .BootReceiver in that case. Thanks, I'll give it a go... Anyone else?